# How to configure Yocto / Boost to support Python 2?

Tags: python, boost, yocto

I can build Yocto Morty for our embedded target and include "libboost_python.so". Now I'm switching over to Rocko (for unrelated reasons) and I can't get that library to be included in the build.

In local.conf, I have:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-boost = "python"
```

which used to be enough on Morty. On Rocko, no matter what I try (variants of PACKAGECONFIG, hacking the boost.inc file - which is mostly greek to me) I can get libboost_python3.so but not libboost_python.so. Presumably, the recipe has changed since Morty to default to not providing Python 2, and I can't find the foo to re-enable it.

What instruction should I put in local.conf in order to force the inclusion of Python 2 support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for python2 in boost has been removed in rocko onwards, see this [bug](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11104)

Its not easy to make both python2 and python3 support to keep together for boost

I think you might want to revert.

http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/?id=0f5418eb0ce12811b16d2e3c28c28140a509f685

Comment: That explains it, thank you. I managed to get my packages that use boost-python to build by linking libboost_python.so to libboost_python3.so. Unexpected, surely. Wise?

Comment: No, not wise it turns out, unsurprisingly. What did work for me was to (sticking with Rocko) using an earlier commit of the recipe for boost, before the upgrade to Python3. Suppress the standard recipe with `BBMASK += ".*recipes-support/boost.*"`.